# Using document.execCommand to interact with WebView

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm using WebView to implement a rich text editor. I have a JavaFX toolbar with control buttons (bold, italic etc.) and a webview below that. When the user clicks a button in the toolbar I use use the javascript command document.execCommand to manipulate the webview.

This works great if nothing is selected in the webview, but if some text is selected and I click the bold button, the text becomes bold but as soon as I unselect the text it gets deleted.

I created a test case with a JavaFX button and a WebView with contenteditable set and a HTML button to show that this doesn't happen when I click that, even though it's using the same document.execCommand as I do with the JavaFX button. It seems to me to be a problem with WebView losing the focus when I click the JavaFX button. Does anyone have a way around this problem or am I doomed to implement the toolbar in HTML?

---

WebViewTest.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewTest extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(getClass().getResource("test.html").toExternalForm());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Bold");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                webView.getEngine().executeScript("bold();");
            }
        });
        box.getChildren().add(button);
        box.getChildren().add(webView);
        root.getChildren().add(box);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>TinyMCE Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.designMode = "on";
        };

        function bold() {
            document.execCommand("bold");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br /><br /><input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="bold();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reproduced on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

Comment: Looks like a WebView bug. May be you should write open an issue http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT

Comment: Opened an issue, http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28827